# Test Javascript file download utility function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, file, jestjs, sinon

I've written utility function to download file which take path as input and download file with name depending on the the path. Here it is:

```
static downloadFile(path) {
  return fetch(path)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    const fileName = path.includes('file1') ? 'file.csv' : 'file2.csv';
    a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })
 }
```

Below is my testing function which is not working. Help me find out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function jsonOk (body) {
  var mockResponse = new window.Response(JSON.stringify(body), {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'text/csv'
    }
  });

  return Promise.resolve(mockResponse);
}

const MOCK_JSON = {
  'key1' : 'value1'
};

describe('Test utils', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      let stub = sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');
      stub.onCall(0).returns(jsonOk(MOCK_JSON));
   });
  afterEach(() => {
      window.fetch.restore();
   });
  it('test csv download', () => {
    const link = {click: sinon.spy();}
    global.URL.createObjectURL = sinon.fake.returns('https://something.com');
    global.URL.revokeObjectURL = sinon.fake();
    global.Blob = function(content, options) {
       return {content, options};
     };
    sinon.Spy(document, 'createElement', () => link);
    // my actual fn call
    Utils.downloadFile('https://something.com/file1');
    expect(link.download).to.equal('file1.csv'); // Chai check
    expect(link.click).should.have.callCount(1);
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is there any error. Show it

Comment: 'expect' are failing because download/click are undefined. When I debugged it, control is not going in the second 'then' block where the actual file download code is present.